# How to replace escape codes in url and redirect it using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I need to redirect multiple urls from this format:

http://site.com/gallery.php%3Fpage%3D12

(the 12 at the end is the page number, i have many links like this with different numbers at the end)

to this:

http://site.com/gallery.php?page=12

how to i write a rule in htaccess that will replace those chars in all the urls and redirect them to the correct urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default URLs in mod_rewrte are decoded(unescaped) so there is no need to escape(encode) them!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by "Death", there is no need to replace the chars, this simple rule did the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^gallery\.php\?page\=(.*) http://site.com/gallery.php?page=$1 [R=301,L]
```